# YugaByte CREATE DATABASE failure

Tags: database, yugabytedb

I tried to run the yugabyte 2.0.8.0 quick start demo according to these instructions:

https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/install/

https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/create-local-cluster/

with 3 local nodes

```
./bin/yb-ctl --rf 3 create
```

And then explore ysql:

https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/quick-start/explore-ysql/

but the db creation fails:

```
yugabyte=# CREATE DATABASE yb_demo;
CREATE DATABASE yb_demo;
ERROR:  Timed out: Write(tablet: 00000000000000000000000000000000, num_ops: 1, num_attempts: 9, txn: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) passed its deadline 3393.992s (passed: 65.317s): Remote error (yb/rpc/outbound_call.cc:440): Service unavailable (yb/tserver/tablet_service.cc:291): Soft memory limit exceeded (at 93.81% of capacity), score: 0.00

yugabyte=# CREATE DATABASE yb_demo;
CREATE DATABASE yb_demo;
ERROR:  Already present: Keyspace 'yb_demo' already exists

yugabyte=# DROP DATABASE yb_demo;
DROP DATABASE yb_demo;
ERROR:  database "yb_demo" does not exist

yugabyte=# \c yb_demo;
FATAL:  database "yb_demo" does not exist
Previous connection kept
```

So the db creation failed. I cannot recreate it but it seems that I also cannot remove it nor connect to it. The error message hints that there was not enough memory.

free output is:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        4045992     1400276     1419504       64104     1226212     2319448
Swap:       4194300           0     4194300
```

Questions:

How much memory is required for running YugaByte? In this case the runtime environment is 4GB Ubuntu 16.4 VirtualBox VM with desktop. Your HW requirements say min 2GB https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/checklist/.

How can I recover this error? Either drop the failed db or finalize the db creation?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: When I created only 1 node, the CREATE DATABASE command succeeded. So maybe 3 nodes in one 4GB VM is too much. But how can I recover from the error?

Comment: Yes, as you correctly pointed out, the requirement is 2GB per node (or process instance). BTW, those recommendations are for multi-node clusters that you intend to run for a long time.

* If you don't care about the data, just do `yb-ctl destroy` and recreate.
* If you want to rescue it, could you please open a github issue? Would be good for us to work thought it there.

Comment: You can get more realtime help in our forum as well. That said, I will also ask some folks more knowledgeable to jump in here to help out.

Comment: It's just a demo so in this case I will destroy the data, but generally there should be way to recover without losing the data.

Comment: Yes, agree. This is definitely being worked on, we can try to add these types of tests to our regression suite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How much memory is required for running YugaByte? In this case the runtime environment is 4GB Ubuntu 16.4 VirtualBox VM with desktop. Your HW requirements say min 2GB https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/deploy/checklist/.

Indeed, the `2GB` minimum is intended to be per node.
Since you are running a `3`-node cluster on one machine, it should help to increase it to `6GB` or more.

Alternatively, if increasing the memory is not an option, you can tune the memory limits for the processes. 
By default Yugabyte allocates `10%` of total memory to the `yb-master` process (metadata server) and `85%` to the `yb-tserver` process (tablet-server).

In your case, the memory issue is most likely with the `yb-master` process (`CREATE DATABASE` command will initialize the metadata for the new database).
You can inspect the current memory settings and usage using the Web UI to confirm.

- `yb-master`: `<node-ip>/7000/mem-trackers`
- `yb-tserver`: `<node-ip>:9000/memz`

Note: for a `3`-node `yb-ctl` cluster the node IPs are typically `127.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.2`, and `127.0.0.3`.

To update the `yb-master` memory limit you can use the `memory_limit_hard_bytes` flag (same flag can be used for the `yb-tserver`).
For instance, to increase it to `600MB`:

```
./bin/yb-ctl stop && ./bin/yb-ctl start --master_flags="memory_limit_hard_bytes=629145600"
```

Note: You can also use the same options directly when creating a cluster:

```
./bin/yb-ctl destroy && ./bin/yb-ctl create --master_flags="memory_limit_hard_bytes=629145600"
```

> How can I recover this error? Either drop the failed db or finalize the db creation?

Regarding the memory issue causing the new database to be left in that state, that can happen in some corner cases in `2.0.8` if the DDL command (`CREATE DATABASE` fails with a system error in the middle).

For now, the simplest fix, if this is a test cluster, is to destroy the cluster and then recreate it (either on a machine with more memory or with updated flags as shown above).
Otherwise you can use the `yb-admin` tool to clean up the partial metadata.

```
./bin/yb-admin delete_namespace ysql.yb_demo
```

Note: Some commits to fix such cases have landed recently [[1]](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/b68b84bfd46b6a771d828c66477a477aa0f71844), [[2]](https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/commit/6994a85679ef798eb032427a8fef7ff842268e6f) and should be in the next release (though I can't confirm if they will fix this particular issue).

Comment: delete_namespace worked after I had first added VM mem to 6GB.